# How to conveniently refactor OCaml project?

Tags: ocaml

I am using `Emacs` + `Tuareg mode` to do my `OCaml` project.

It is working fine and I get used to it.

However, along with my project source base getting bigger and bigger, I find managing the project is getting harder and harder.

Especially for `refactoring`. If I change a module name or function name, I have to search everywhere for the part that need to changed accordingly or I just constantly compile again and again to let compiler tell me where I should go.

It is not convenient.

Anyone can suggest a good way for source base management?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good option is [TypeRex](http://www.typerex.org/old.html). This is an alternative Emacs mode created by OCamlPro that has a bunch of OCaml-aware features including proper support for refactoring (like renaming identifiers).

It also has a bunch of other nice features like good auto-complete, semantic grep and so on.

Unfortunately, this involves changing your build process to use some wrapper programs. These generate the additional information the mode needs to function. However, once you get the build set up, it's a really awesome editing environment.

Comment: but i guess TypeRex is not for 4.00.1, at least no stable version for 4.00.1

Comment: Oh yeah, maybe not. However, they might have a beta version with support for new features--it's probably worth sending them an email. I can't actually use it myself, so I haven't kept up with developments.

Comment: I am using 4.00.1 and typerex together, but I never tried the refactoring functionality.

Comment: Interestingly there was a small emacs clone written in ocaml a long time ago. I wonderif typerex could've been integrated easily there. using ocaml for scripting _is_ an appealing perspective.